# Using からが、からで、からに and からは

Tags: particles, particle-から

> 「たんじょうびに　[田中]{たなか}さん**から（　）**　[何]{なに}を　もらったんですか。」

I'm given the choices からが、からで、　からに　and からは.

The problem is when I've used online dictionaries they tell me different meanings for these phrasal expressions. I know that から　by itself generally means from as in something from someone or somewhere. What I am confused about is the particle being used at after から. Can someone explain what the differences are?

Answer (score 6):

> 「たんじょうびに　[田中]{たなか}さん**から（　）**　[何]{なに}を　もらったんですか。」
>
> = "What did you get from Tanaka for your birthday?"

The sentence is already grammatical without a word in the blank after 「から」, but if you had to place one, 「**は**」 woud be the only correct particle among the four.

Why 「は」, then?  This 「は」 in 「田中さんから**は**」 is the ***contrastive*** 「は」, ***not*** the subject-marker 「は」 that I would assume you are familiar with.  The subject of this sentence is the unmentioned "***you***", not 「田中さん」 or the unmentioned "***I***".

How does the contrastive 「は」 fit in there?  In short, the context.  If the topic of a conversation were birthday presents, there would often be an assumption that one would receive presents from multiple people.

The nuance of the sentence with 「は」 is: "Among all the people who gave you presents, what did ***Tanaka*** give you?"

Moving on...

I will give a brief explanation of the other three phrases, but ***I would seriously warn you*** that reading it could only confuse you further if you currently were a real beginner. Some of the things, I will have no choice but to mention, belong to way above the intermediate level.

**First, 「からが」.**

> 「Noun + （にして） + から + が」  (にして is optional)
>
> = "even (noun), possibly among other things"

https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%81%8C-467244

To use an example from that dictionary,

「大きさにして**からが**私の物にそっくりだ。」 = "Even the size of it looks just like that of mine."

**Next, 「からで」.**

It is the continuative form of 「からだ」= "because ~~"

「レレクトゥールさんと結婚したいのは、お金持ちになりたい**からで**、彼を愛しているからではありません。」

= "The reason I want to marry l'électeur is because I want to be wealthy, not because I love him."

**Finally, 「からに」.**

It has several meanings and usages, but I will only talk about the most common one, which is "by only (verb)ing".

https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%81%AB-467569#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88

An example from there is 「聞く**からに**強そうな名前」= "a strong-sounding name". (You do not even have to look at the kanji or anything to say it is strong.)

Comment: is が in 「からが」the subject marker or the contrast marker?